# Using setattr() on a UI element

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit, setattr

I am trying to use setattr on a UI element (QLineEdit) to fill in with what was read from a text file.   I believe in order to set a QlineEdit it would be *self.lineEdit.setText()*

The text file I am reading consists of a Name and it's value:

Name1=Value1

splitLine[0] consists of "Name1", and splitLine[1] is "Value1".  self.Name1 is the name of the lineEdit I am changing, hence I used eval() to pass the actual value "Name1" to setattr.

I am not sure how to go about setting the value.  Right now I have tried these with no success:

```
setattr(self, eval("splitLine[0]"), eval("splitLine[1]"))

setattr(self, eval("splitLine[0]"), setText(eval("splitLine[1]")))
```

Also, using:

```
self.splitLine[0].setText(splitLine[1])
```

Does not work as it thinks the actual object is called splitLine, rather than it's value (hence why I tried eval() ).

```
# AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'splitLine'
```

Comment: What attributes are you trying to set?  Most Qt objects don't have any attributes you can set.  You normally have to use the accessor/mutator methods.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any need of your `eval` calls, since you're using a constant string for each of them. Why not just use `splitline[0]` and `splitline[1]`?

Comment: self.splitLine[0].setText(splitLine[1]) is not valid

The Qt object I am setting is:   self.Name1

and

splitLine[0] = "Name1"

How am I to get that value out of splitLine[0] in order to set the Qt object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `getattr`, not `setattr`. That is, you first need to **get** the line-edit object (via its attribute name), so that you can then call its `setText` method to populate the field:

```
    lineEdit = getattr(self, splitLine[0])
    lineEdit.setText(splitLine[1])
```

or in one line:

```
    getattr(self, splitLine[0]).setText(splitLine[1])
```

Comment: I am trying to set a QLineEdit UI field.  Why would I use getattr?  I am confused.

Comment: @sz200. I have updated my answer to make it clearer. Did you actually try the code?

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro.  But I would like to understand this.  why would assigning the value to another variable lineEdit, and then calling setText on lineEdit give me the result?  But say... 

    self.splitLine[0].setText(splitLine[1])

Will not and instead I get:
    # AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'splitLine'?  I just don't get it and would like to understand the logic.

Comment: The [getattr](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function allows you to get an attribute by using a string corresponding to its name. The actual attribute name of your line-edit is "Name1", not "splitline[0]". You need to be able to do `self.Name1.setText(splitline[1])`. The `self.Name1` part is done by `getattr(self, splitline[0])`, where `splitline[0]` *contains* the string "Name1".

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `eval`; `splitLine` contains strings, which is the required type for the second argument and sufficient for the third argument.

```
setattr(self, splitLine[0], splitLine[1])
```